# iphond-uitaleview-uipopovercontrol-uiscrollview

Tags: iphone

In UITableview, When I Click On Cell  One Popup Window Is Open For That I am using UIPopOverControl.. And Inside UIPopOverControl One View Which IS Generated Programmatically, That Is  Assign to UIPopOverControl..

In  That View There Are So Many UIButton (About 3 Columns And 10 Rows Of Button)
These Buttons are Generated Programmatically Also..

Now My problem is , I Want To Scroll On UIPOPOverControl Or View Inside Of UIPopOverControl...

Because At A Time I View Only 5 row Of Button..

I Dont Want To Use UITableView....

Any On Help Me ?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add View with buttons in UIscrollView.Set ContentSize of scrollview according to buttons size you are inserting in View.
Then add this UIScrollView to UIPopOVerView.

Comment: I Was Try But not Working Properly , Because I Generate All Things IN Programmatically,,, Like , 1 : UIViewController , Then UIView ... IN UIView I PLace Buttons ,, Then UIViewController.view=UIView. And Then UIViewController Place On UIpopOverCotrol